# Regular expressions test function. Visualizing code

Tags: regex, python-3.x, search, line, python-re

I have the following code:

```
from sys import stdin
import re

def main():
    def hidden1_test(): return hidden1('test')
    def hidden2_test(): return hidden2('test')
    tasks = [dna, sorted, hidden1_test, hidden2_test, equation, parentheses, sorted3]
    print('Skriv in teststrängar:')
    while True:
        line = stdin.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
        if line == '': break
        for task in tasks:
            result = '' if re.search(task(), line) else 'INTE '
            print('%s(): "%s" matchar %suttrycket "%s"' % (task.__name__, line, result, task()))

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Functions in the list tasks are defined above but they are not important for my question. I understand the entire run of the function main up until the last two rows:

```
result = '' if re.search(task(), line) else 'INTE '    
print('%s(): "%s" matchar %suttrycket "%s"' % (task.__name__, line, result, task()))
```

I don't understand what `task.__name__` means. Name must be `__name__ == '__main__'` so i suppose my question becomes what does `task.'__main__'` mean (correct me if i am wrong)? I interpret the first row of the two above as:

```
result = '' 
if re.search(task(), line): 
else:
    'INTE '
```

I know this can't be right since there is nothing under the if statement, but I don't know how to test the code to get an understanding of what it means. I am just trying to get a better understanding so an explanation for someone who is not a very advanced programmer would be nice

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions here.

### What is `__name__`?

In Python, `__name__` is a special attribute automatically created for some type of constructs like modules, classes, functions, etc. (see [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for more details)

In your code, it is used twice :

- `task.__name__` will be the name of whatever `task` represents. I guess it will be a function in your code.

  For example, for the task `hidden1_test`, `task.__name__` will be `'hidden1_test'`.
- `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` is a classic way in Python to determine if the current script is the *main* Python program.

  Here, `__name__` is the name of the current module. If it equals to the value `'__main__'`, then it means the current script **is** the *main* program.

  You can find more information on this in [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

### How does work `result = 'A' if matches else 'B'`?

This is a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), also known as *ternary operator*.

In most languages inspired by C, the same code will be written `result = matches ? 'A' : 'B'`.

If the return value of `re.search(task(), line)` is [*truthy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), the variable `result` will be assigned the value `''`. If not, it will be assigned the value `'INTE '`.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list of tasks.

```
tasks = [dna, sorted, hidden1_test, hidden2_test, equation, parentheses, sorted3]
```

You do not know when those tasks will end, so you keep checking until they are finished : `while True:`

To know which one is still running, you read a line from the standard input.

```
line = stdin.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
```

see: [python 3.8.2, stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

If all tasks are finished, you have nothing to read, you break out of the while loop and end the program.

```
if line == '': break

# same as
if line == '':
  break
```

For informational purpose we want to print which tasks are still running and which ones have been **INTE**rupted.

*Is this task still running (is the task name found in `line`)?*

First we use regex, which is a tool to search for patterns in text.

```
re.search(pattern, text) # Return true if it found something!
```

[Play with  RegExr](https://regexr.com/), you'll see that it's pretty cool.

Then, if the task is not found (it is finished), we add INTE to mean that it has been interrupted.

```
result = '' if re.search(task(), line) else 'INTE '

# Above is a ternary operator, which is the same as...
if re.search(task(), line) :
  result = ''
else:
  result = 'INTE'
```

Here we use what most people call a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions).

... and then, we print a text. `task.__name__` is simply the name of the task. Most likely, your `task` is an object, and this object has a name. A good guess would be that your task name could be `dna`, `sorted`, `hidden1_test`, ...

Comment: Thanks! That made things a lot easier to understand